# ConcurrentHashMap without synchronized keyword

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap<String,List<String>>` that is accessed by threads which check if the key exists before appending a value. I got this working with the use of `synchronized` keyword. If `synchronized` keyword is not used then the values are wrong. Isn't `ConcurrentHashMap` threadsafe? Or is there a issue with this code? Is is possible to get this code working without using `synchronized` to achieve better performance? Here is the code that does that.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future<?>> futures = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future<?>>();
        final ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        File[] files = new File(dir).listFiles();
for (final File tfile : files) {
                futures.add((Future<String>) executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(tfile.getAbsolutePath()));
                        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) obj;
                        String documentname = obj.get("name").toString();
                        synchronized (map) {
                            List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
                            //if key already exists append new path to the value
                            if (map.containsKey(documentname)) {
                                paths = map.get(documentname);
                            }
                            paths.add(tfile.getAbsolutePath());
                            map.put(documentname, paths);
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
```

Comment: Using a threadsafe datastructure does not mean that Java stops all multithreading in your program. You still need atomic blocks. `ConcurrentHashMap` provides an atomic `putIfAbsent` method, use that. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-

Comment: @SkinnyJ Thanks for pointing out putIfAbsent .. really helpful atomic method..

Comment: keep in mind that `putIfAbsent` on the `Map` interface (introduced in Java 8) makes no guarantees about atomicity. You must be using a `ConcurrentMap` implementation that obeys its contract. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-

Comment: Oh i see. Ya using ConcurrentMap makes sense in a multithreaded scenario..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try replacing this:

```
String documentname = obj.get("name").toString();
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
//if key already exists append new path to the value
if (map.containsKey(documentname)) {
    paths = map.get(documentname);
}
paths.add(tfile.getAbsolutePath());
map.put(documentname, paths);
```

with this:

```
String documentname = obj.get("name").toString();
List<String> paths = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
List<String> existing = map.putIfAbsent(documentname, paths);
if (existing != null) {
    paths = existing;
}
paths.add(tfile.getAbsolutePath());
```

The [putIfAbsent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)) method avoids a race condition that occurs if two threads both try to check (using containsKey) then put an entry into the map.

The [synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) method wraps the nested collection with a synchronized wrapper, so that you don't need to synchronize accesses to the nested collection. Alternatively, you could use a concurrent data structure from java.util.concurrent.

[ThreadSafe](http://www.contemplateltd.com/threadsafe) is a static analysis tool that finds concurrency bugs. It can run standalone, in Eclipse or be used as a SonarQube plugin. In particular, it has a checkers for the two bugs in the code you've shown:

- Non-atomic use of get-check-put (which can be replaced with putIfAbsent) ([example report](http://download.contemplateltd.com/projects/examples/index.html#by-type/17/0/24))
- Shared non-threadsafe content in a concurrent collection ([example report](http://download.contemplateltd.com/projects/examples/index.html#by-type/18/0/34))

One problem with the code using putIfAbsent that I've suggested is that it always creates a collection. When the map already contains an entry for the given key, the new collection is simply discarded. However, this *may* be inefficient for your application, and can put extra pressure on the garbage collector.

Therefore, you might want to consider something like this:

```
String documentname = obj.get("name").toString();
List<String> paths = map.get(documentname);
if (paths == null) {
   paths = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
   List<String> existing = map.putIfAbsent(documentname, paths);
   if (existing != null) {
       paths = existing;
   }
   paths.add(tfile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Note the "Rule Description" link in bottom-left of the screen in this ThreadSafe [non-atomic get-check-put](http://download.contemplateltd.com/projects/examples/index.html#by-type/17/0/24) link. Click the "Rule Description" link for further explanation of the get-check-put problem, and possible solutions to it.

Comment: Should there be a map.put(documentname, paths); at the end in your modified code? Is that put threadsafe again?

Comment: No, no put intended. This has been replaced by putIfAbsent.

Comment: Sorry about the mistakes in earlier edits of this answer. I think I've fixed them all now.

Comment: Great works now.. I didn't know about this putIfAbsent method!

Answer (score 2):

ConcurrentHashMap is thread-safe, but that doesn't mean anything you do with a ConcurrentHashMap is. There are several problems in the code, if synchronized isn't used:

1. You're accessing an ArrayList concurrently, from multiple threads. An ArrayList is not thread-safe
2. You're doing several operations (`containKey`, `get`, `put`) in sequence on the Map. Each of these operations is thread-safe and atomic, but the sequence of operations is not. If you need that sequence of operations to be atomic, then you need to synchronize. Or you need to use an equivalent atomic operation: `putIfAbsent`().

Comment: +1 for describing the real problem:  Building a program out of thread-safe classes does not make the program thread-safe.